# ASP.NET MVC "Loading..." gif during initial API call

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application that displays different data depending on the id number in the query string. It's designed to give users safety information specific to them based on what county they live in, what type of job they have, etc. They don't use a user name to log in, they just click on a link in their email like: http://www.mysite.com?id=123456

In `Session_Start` of `global.asax`, I pull down their id from the query string and search for a record that matches through an API call. This returns a bunch of fields in a DataSet which I turn into a DataTable. I then use a foreach loop to loop through the DataTable and use `Session.Add(name, value)` to create the session variables which I will plug into the view.

It can take up to 10 seconds for the API call to go through, so I want to put up some sort of "Loading..." gif animation until the API call is complete. Once the initial API call is complete I don't have to do any more API calls.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a loading animation, then you need a rendered HTML page. That means making your API call via AJAX. You can still encapsulate the call in your own view, just call your view with AJAX. Once you're initiating the call with JavaScript, it's trivial to add a loading animation. If you don't use AJAX, there's nothing you can do about it, as the server won't return the response until the view has finished processing.